# Reload router link onclick

Tags: angular

Is there any way to refresh a router link with button click?

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="clickme()"></button>
```

**TS**

```
clickme(){
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/abc/a/']);
}
```

When I click the button it has to reload and view.

Comment: Hello Felix, Can you be more specific please. What means refreshing a router-link ?

Comment: If I click it should refresh first and then show component

Comment: Seems likes an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Explain what you are facing please.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your component and navigate to the same URL.

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

And call the following method for refresh:

```
clickme(){
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/abc/a/']);
}
```